# Visual Studio - C# Auto Format - Wrapping to 100 columns

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I can't for the life of me find out how to get visual studio to keep my source to 100 columns width as part of auto-format.

```
Ctrl+K+D
```

Surely this doesn't require an extension? What's the simplest way to set it up?

Comment: you must have a tiny monitor to need to wrap to 100 columns :(

Comment: 30 inch - It's just for readability, If I have a bunch of text I don't want to manually wrap the line. I also like to have multiple source files open without overlap. It's also good for reading via the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible as part of auto-format. If you use a tool like [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), it does have this option, but I don't think it works in all scenarios such as wrapping strings, for example (i.e. `string x = "<over 100 characters here>"` is not going to be corrected).

I think the best thing to do is to [use a guideline](http://blogs.msdn.com/saraford/archive/2004/05/05/257953.aspx) in the editor. Then, as you write your code you can just make sure you don't go past the guideline. Not the ideal solution, but it works pretty well.